# How to swipe right or left to get next activity detail that was started from a listview intent

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

So I have a listview that is populated by a xml array list. When I click a row in the list it starts a new activity via intent to a details page. I want to be able to swipe right or left to get the next detail page that corresponds with the next row in the listview. I've set up my onSwipeRight and onSwipeLeft which work but I don't know what to put inside them to populate the next/previous details page.

Here's my main activity with the list view and the on click listener to pass the relevant information to the details activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MyDBHandler dbHandler;
int listViewPosition;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    //Action Bar customization
    final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //fill list view with xml array of routes
    final CharSequence[] routeListViewItems = getResources().getTextArray(R.array.routeList);
    ////fill list view with xml array of route numbers
    final TypedArray routeNumberImages = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.routeNumberImages);
    //fills route detail text view with xml array info
    final CharSequence[] routeDetail= getResources().getTextArray(R.array.routeDetail);
    //fills route detail image view with xml array of images
    final TypedArray image = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.routeImages);


    //custom adapter for list view
    ListAdapter routeAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, routeListViewItems, routeNumberImages);
    final ListView routeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.routeListView);
    routeListView.setAdapter(routeAdapter);

    //sets first visible list item
    listViewPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("listViewPosition", 0);
    routeListView.setSelectionFromTop(listViewPosition, 0);

    routeListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    CharSequence route = routeListViewItems[position];
                    int imageId = (int) image.getResourceId(position, -1);
                    if (route.equals(routeListViewItems[position]))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RouteDetails.class);
                        intent.putExtra("route", routeDetail[position]);
                        intent.putExtra("imageResourceId", imageId);
                        intent.putExtra("routeName", routeListViewItems[position]);
                        intent.putExtra("listViewPosition", position);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

and heres my details page with the onswipe listener

```
public class RouteDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
MyDBHandler dbHandler;
ImageView routeImage;
String routeName;
CharSequence route;
CheckBox routeCheckBox;
int listViewPosition;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_details);

    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);

    //sets actionbar title
    routeName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("routeName");
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(routeName);

    //TextView for route details
    final TextView routeDetailsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.routeDetailsView);
    route = getIntent().getExtras().getCharSequence("route");
    routeDetailsView.setText(route);

    //ImageView for route details
    routeImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.routeImage);
    final int mImageResource = getIntent().getIntExtra("imageResourceId", 0);
    routeImage.setImageResource(mImageResource);

    ///gets position of row that was clicked to pass into database
    listViewPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("listViewPosition", 0);


    ///////////////

    routeDetailsView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            // Whatever
            Intent i = new Intent(RouteDetails.this,RouteDetails.class);

            startActivity(i);
        }

    @Override
    public void onSwipeRight() {
        // Whatever
        Intent i = new Intent(RouteDetails.this,RouteDetails.class);

        startActivity(i);
    }

    });

    ///////////////

}
```

Thank you for any help!

edit with error after implementing new code

```
01-04 12:55:51.694 25443-25443/com.example.zach.listview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.zach.listview, PID: 25443
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zach.listview/com.example.zach.listview.RouteDetails}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
                                                                           at com.example.zach.listview.RouteDetails.onCreate(RouteDetails.java:56)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a single item to your details page, you should pass the entire array as well as the current position (which you already do).

In your click event (MainActivity), replace:

```
intent.putExtra("route", routeDetail[position]);
intent.putExtra("routeName", routeListViewItems[position]);
```

with:

```
intent.putExtra("routes", routeDetail);
intent.putExtra("routeNames", routeListViewItems);
```

In RouteDetails you would need to get the arrays and the current objects:

```
CharSequence[] routes;
CharSequence[] routeNames;

// ...

listViewPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("listViewPosition", 0);

routes = getIntent().getExtras().getCharSequenceArray("routes");
routeNames = getIntent().getExtras().getCharSequenceArray("routeNames");

route = routes[listViewPosition];
routeName = routeNames[listViewPosition];
```

And in your swipe events, just pass in the arrays along with the previous or next index:

```
routeDetailsView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
    @Override
    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        // Whatever
        Intent i = new Intent(RouteDetails.this,RouteDetails.class);
        i.putExtra("routes", routes);
        i.putExtra("routeNames", routeNames);
        i.putExtra("imageResourceId", imageId);
        i.putExtra("listViewPosition", position + 1);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipeRight() {
        // Whatever
        Intent i = new Intent(RouteDetails.this,RouteDetails.class);
        i.putExtra("routes", routes);
        i.putExtra("routeNames", routeNames);
        i.putExtra("imageResourceId", imageId);
        i.putExtra("listViewPosition", position - 1);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: So I added the code you supplied but now I'm getting a null pointer exception on a null array.

Comment: I just edited my answer, I had the variable names mixed up. If you still have an error, can you tell me on which line?

Comment: I had noticed that and changed them when I tried your code but that didn't work. I put the error log up in my original post. Thanks!

Comment: What is line 56 of your `RouteDetails.java`?

Comment: So I was able to get it to work. I had to change a couple things. I got rid of the route and routeName variables and set the resources like routeDetailsView.setText(routes[listViewPosition]); and that seemed to make it work. I also had to change position in the putExtra to listViewPosition. Thank you!